# Indexing the laply function with a name

Tags: r

I have a list, one element of which is shown below

```
[[1]]

[[1]]$`id`

[1] "id"

[[1]]$num

[1] 100
```

To extract all the "num" elements from the list, I can use the following

```
nums=laply(x,`[[`,2)
```

Is there any way to replace the 2 in the laply expression with something like $num?

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways to share data that can be copy/pasted into R. Be sure to give the desired output for your sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be sufficient to replace `2` with `"num"`, like in the example below.

```
x <- rep(list(list(id = "id", num = 100)), 3)

nums <- lapply(x,`[[`,2)

nums2 <- lapply(x,`[[`, "num")

identical(nums, nums2)
[1] TRUE
```